# Why does CocoaPods target have build settings?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Why do our CocoaPods targets have different build settings than our actual project target settings? Shouldn't it just have project target settings? How does it work when our project is being compiled; does the compiler look at the CocoaPods settings or just our project target settings? If so, then what is the purpose of CocoaPods having its own build settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CocoaPods generally are built as a framework in iOS, and frameworks can have different settings than the main application, and are built as a separate bundle. Every compile-unit (more or less "source file") can also have its own settings (at least in ObjC; I've never tried that in Swift).

There are lots of reasons to have different compile settings for different parts of the program, and specifically for third-party code. For example, you might want to compile third-party code with a higher optimization level and debug stripping if you don't plan to debug that portion. I personally turn off all warnings in third-party code.

It's not as common anymore, but during the ARC transition it was very common to compile some of the program with ARC and some without. As Swift evolves, you should expect it become more common for libraries to be written in source-incompatible versions of Swift that require different settings.

Comment: ok, thanks so if the frameworks im using dont have any instructions to change build settings and everything is building fine I should leave all the settings as is then right ?

Comment: Yeah, you generally shouldn't modify them directly. If you want to modify CocoaPod build settings, you would do that in your Podfile. For example, I generally include `inhibit_all_warnings!`. CP will take care of building the project correctly.